# How do you set up scoped mass-assignment while using cancan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise, cancan

Let's say I have a model "Channel" as such (Course is a boolean attribute):

```
class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title
  attr_accessible :course, :title, :as => :administrator
end
```

I'm using cancan with the following ability setup:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user
      if user.administrator
        can :manage, Channel
      else
        can [:read, :create], Channel
        can [:update, :destroy], Channel, :course => false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here's my current controller setup:

```
class ChannelsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  ###

  def new
  end

  def create
    if @channel.save
      redirect_to @channel, :notice => "Successfully created channel."
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @channel.update_attributes(params[:channel])
      redirect_to @channel, :notice  => "Successfully updated channel."
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  ###

end
```

I need cancan's `load_and_authorize_resource` method in my controller to prevent non-administrator users from having the ability to update an existing channel where course is true, but I also need to interrupt its resource loading with an if/else based on `current_user.administrator` to set the `:as => :administrator` scope so administrators have access to the course attribute.

Is there a sensible way to do this?

Comment: I ended up splitting channels and courses into two separate models because there was enough separation in how I wanted to handle each that it made better sense than keeping them as one model. That probably doesn't help you much, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the `update` method is pretty straightforward because the mass-assignment is done by `update_attributes` and not in `load_and_authorize_resource`:

```rb
def update
  @channel.assign_attributes(params[:channel],
            :as => (current_user.administrator ? :administrator : :default)
  if @channel.save
    redirect_to @channel, :notice  => "Successfully updated channel."
  else
    render :action => 'edit'
  end
end
```

For the `create` action I think the easiest solution is to do the assignment and the authorization manually:

```rb
load_and_authorize_resource :except => :create

## ----

def create
  @channel = Channel.new
  @channel.assign_attributes(params[:channel],
            :as => (current_user.administrator ? :administrator : :default)
  if @channel.save
    redirect_to @channel, :notice => "Successfully created channel."
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

If you end up doing this a lot, it might be worth it to use a simple custom filter instead of `load_and_authorize_resource`.